# put all imgs from current directory inside array PHP

Tags: php, sprite

Im trying to put all .PNG files inside an array with its details.

Here is my code:

```
$imgs = glob($path . "*.png");

$tab_img = [];

foreach($imgs as $value){
    $img_png = imagecreatefrompng($value);
    $tab_img['name'] = $value;
    $tab_img['width'] = imagesx($img_png);
    $tab_img['height'] = imagesy($img_png);
}

print_r($tab_img);
```

Here is what is displays :

```
Array

    (
        [name] => ./sprite.png
        [width] => 300
        [height] => 300
    )
```

It only takes on image inside the folder when in fact, there is many more...

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: You overwrite the same index (for example `$tab_img['name'] = ...`). How are you expecting to recieve multiple entries?

Answer (score 2):

In each loop, you are overwriting the same elements in the array, you should build the image data and then add it to the array...

```
$img_png = imagecreatefrompng($value);
$tab_img[] = [
    'name' => $value, 
    'width' => imagesx($img_png),
    'height' => imagesy($img_png),
];
```